# Can I override a style?

Tags: html, css

Can I override my `<p>` style, having my class mainbookingleftadditional font style work instead?

code:

```
<div class="mainbookingleftadditional"><p>Please inform us of anything you... </p></div>
```

css:

```
p  {font-size:14px;}

.mainbookingleftadditional {
    float: left;
    width: 228px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    font: 8px "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    clear:both;
}
```

Regards,
Tea

Comment: You need to assign the class to the `p`

Comment: Style by default are inherited to child nodes, what specifically in that class you need to be applied to your p?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to only change the property for every `p` inside every `mainbookingleftadditional`, you can use the following:

```
.mainbookingleftadditional p  {font-size:8px;}
```

this will override the regular `p` definition because it has a higher [specificity](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity) (more specific)

Specificity is what decides which css definitions your element will use, in case some elements have more than one definition.

**EDIT:**

Seeing the other answers i must add that using !important for such a case is a bad idea.

!important is a very powerful case and should only be used when all other options are depleted.

Answer (score 1):

You use `inherit` for your font property to make sure it uses the font styles defined in your `mainbookingleftadditional` class.

```
p {
   font: inherit;
}
```

Comment: But I want the original font side in P to stay as it is.  For it works with other parts of my website.  I just want to override this time only.

Comment: In that case, you can use `.mainbookingleftadditional p { .. }` as in Rodik's answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is either remove `p  {font-size:14px;}` bacause stlye specified in child nodes are preferred to parent style or add `mainbookingleftadditional` class to `p`.

```
 <div class="mainbookingleftadditional"><p class="mainbookingleftadditional">Please inform us of anything you... </p></div>
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TcHnd/) JsFiddle

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you just need to add !important on the end of the style.

```
p  {font-size:14px !important;}
```

Comment: !important is a sign of failure.

Comment: `!important` is strongly discouraged, and should be used only in extreme cases. You need only make it slightly more specific. An `!important`is impossible to override (except with another `!important`).

Answer (score -1):

```
.mainbookingleftadditional p {
    font:inherit;
    }
```

Also, if you want to remove the margin at the top of the paragraph:

```
.mainbookingleftadditional p:first-child {
    margin-top:0;
    padding-top:0;
    }
```